# Check type in C# 5.0 as in C# 7.0

Tags: c#, compatibility

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cm435cCVKCg), and at 16:16 it uses the following condition checking, which is a way to do it in C# 7.0 as far as I know.

```
if(Application.Current.MainWindow is MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    mainWindow.Start_Btn.Ischecked = false;
}
```

My question here is how to do the same using C# 5.0.

I've tried stating a variable of the type before the if statement but with no results, and to be honest I don't have much idea of how to do it.

```
MainWindow mw;
        
if(Application.Current.MainWindow is mw)
{
    mw.Start_Btn.Ischecked = false;
}
```

Edit: I have already checked the documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns)), but it all refers to C# 7.0, and I'm trying to do it in 5.0 because some limitations I have at the moment.

---

Another edit:
Same result can be obtained by

```
var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
window.Start_Btn.IsChecked = false;
window = null;
```

It doesn't check the type of `Application.Current.MainWindow` with a fancy declaration pattern inside an if statement, but it kind of works.

Comment: You need an explicit cast, either using `as MainWindow` (with a `null` check) or `(MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow` with exception handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you see in the tutorial is pattern matching. Unfortunately, as you said, it is a newer syntax.

With older C# versions, you should do it like this:

```cs
MainWindow mw = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
        
if (mw != null)
{
    mw.Start_Btn.Ischecked = false;
}
```

With this, you are trying to get `Application.Current.MainWindow` as a `MainWindow`. If it is of type `MainWindow`, `mw` variable will contain the object `Application.Current.MainWindow` in it (reference of it, of course). Otherwise, `mw` variable will be null. This is why the null checking works.

Actually, this pattern was so common in older applications written in C#, so that Microsoft added the pattern matching syntax to shorten it and make it more readable.

For more info: [Pattern matching overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching)